# Mocking a resolve in $dialog

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I've been creating an angularjs framework for an application I'm planning to write.  At the moment I'm working on a sample application, I'm documenting as I go [in a tutorial](http://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/angularjs-and-rails-tutorial-index/) so that I have everything I did in one place.

I'm currently trying to create unit tests using karma and jasmine for the modal dialog I'm presenting.  This modal dialog is created using the $dialog service from angular-bootstrap.  This dialog I think is using a promise to pass data into the dialog controller, and I'd like to resolve that promise so I can check in my unit test that the data that has been passed in is as expected.  I'm having a little difficulty in working out how to resolve that, I see examples using either scope.$apply or scope.$digest, neither appear to work and to be frank I don't quite understand what it's doing.  I'm concerned that in the unit test I have assigned this promise to a variable, and perhaps that it won't resolve once assigned to a variable.  I see mention that this "resolve" parameter is similar to the resolve on a route, but so far that hasn't helped me, and I'm not 100% sure that it's really a promise at all.

I'm looking both for something that makes it work, but also an explanation of why that works.

The controller I'm seeking to test looks like this:

```
.controller( 'ClubCtrl', function ClubController( $scope, ClubRes, $dialog ) {
  $scope.clubs = ClubRes.query();

  /* this is called from a button, which passes one of the clubs from $scope.clubs */
  $scope.editClub = function(club) {
    $scope.myDialog = $dialog.dialog({dialogFade: false, resolve: {club: function(){return angular.copy(club);}}});
    $scope.myDialog.open('club/club_edit.tpl.html', 'ClubEditCtrl').then(function(result){
      if (result === 'cancel'){}
      else {
        $scope.clubs = ClubRes.query();
      }
    });  
  };
})
```

The unit test I'm trying to get working at this point is aiming to mock out the whole dialog, and to check that the dialog has been called with the correct input parameters:

```
describe( 'Base club controller', function() {
  var scope, httpBackend;

  //mock Application to allow us to inject our own dependencies
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('league'));

  //mock the controller for the same reason and include $rootScope and $controller
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_ ){
    //create an empty scope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    // setup a mock for the resource - instead of calling the server always return a pre-canned response
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    httpBackend.when('GET', '../clubs.json').respond([
      {"contact_officer":"Officer 1","created_at":"2012-02-02T00:00:00Z","date_created":"2012-01-01T00:00:00Z","id":1,"name":"Club 1","updated_at":"2012-03-03T00:00:00Z"},
      {"contact_officer":"Officer 2","created_at":"2012-02-02T00:00:00Z","date_created":"2012-01-01T00:00:00Z","id":2,"name":"Club 2","updated_at":"2012-03-03T00:00:00Z"}]);

    // setup a mock for the dialog - when called it returns the value that was input when it was instantiated
    scope.fakeDialog = {
      parameters: null,
      response: null,
      template: null,
      controller: null,
      dialog: function(parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
        return this;
      },
      open: function(template, controller) {
        this.template = template;
        this.controller = controller;
        return this;
      },
      then: function(callBack){
        callBack(this.response);
      }
    };

    //declare the controller and inject our empty scope
    $controller('ClubCtrl', {$scope: scope, $dialog: scope.fakeDialog});
  }));

  it('Calls edit on first row', function() {
    // check nothing set beforehand
    expect(scope.fakeDialog.parameters).toBe(null);
    expect(scope.fakeDialog.template).toBe(null);
    expect(scope.fakeDialog.controller).toBe(null);

    // call edit
    scope.editClub(scope.clubs[0]);
    scope.$digest();
    httpBackend.flush();

    // expect stuff to have happened
    expect(scope.fakeDialog.parameters.club.name).toBe('Club 1');
    expect(scope.fakeDialog.template).toBe('club/club_edit.tpl.html');
    expect(scope.fakeDialog.controller).toBe('ClubEditCtrl');
  });

});
```

What I'm actually getting in console.log(scope.fakeDialog.parameters) is:

```
Object{dialogFade: false, resolve: Object{club: function (){ ... }}}
```

So my club is buried inside "resolve: Object......", which I think is a promise.  I think what I need is a way to trigger that to resolve - but I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, no responses as yet, and I've had the time tonight to piece through it slowly.

The short answer is that the resolve parameter to a dialog isn't necessarily a promise (although I think it can be sometimes if you wish it to be).  Since I haven't passed in a promise I can directly evaluate these functions to work out their results, although I thought I'd tried that before and it didn't work.

I've also spent some time looking at spyOn, and I can use that for some of the things I had my mock doing, so I'm tidying that up at the same time.

My working code is as follows. Firstly, the controller that's being tested:

```
.controller( 'ClubCtrl', function ClubController( $scope, ClubRes, $dialog ) {
  $scope.clubs = ClubRes.query();

  /* this is called from a button, which passes one of the clubs from $scope.clubs */
  $scope.editClub = function(club) {
    $scope.myDialog = $dialog.dialog({dialogFade: false, resolve: {club: function(){return angular.copy(club);}}});
    $scope.myDialog.open('club/club_edit.tpl.html', 'ClubEditCtrl').then(function(result){
      if (result === 'cancel'){}
      else {
        $scope.clubs = ClubRes.query();
      }
    });  
  };
})
```

Then, the test code that tests that:

```
describe( 'Base club controller', function() {
  var scope, httpBackend;

  //mock Application to allow us to inject our own dependencies
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('league'));

  //mock the controller for the same reason and include $rootScope and $controller
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_ ){
    //create an empty scope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    // setup a mock for the resource - instead of calling the server always return a pre-canned response
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    httpBackend.when('GET', '../clubs.json').respond([
       {"contact_officer":"Officer 1","created_at":"2012-02-02T00:00:00Z","date_created":"2012-01-01T00:00:00Z","id":1,"name":"Club 1","updated_at":"2012-03-03T00:00:00Z"},
      {"contact_officer":"Officer 2","created_at":"2012-02-02T00:00:00Z","date_created":"2012-01-01T00:00:00Z","id":2,"name":"Club 2","updated_at":"2012-03-03T00:00:00Z"}]);

    // setup a mock for the dialog - when called it returns the value that was input when it was instantiated
    scope.fakeDialog = {
      response: null,
      club: null,
      dialog: function(parameters) {
        this.club = parameters.resolve.club();
        return this;
      },
      open: function(template, controller) {
        return this;
      },
      then: function(callBack){
        callBack(this.response);
      }
    };

    //declare the controller and inject our empty scope
    $controller('ClubCtrl', {$scope: scope, $dialog: scope.fakeDialog});
  }));

  it('Calls edit on first row', function() {
    // we expect the fakeDialog dialog and open methods to be called, so we spy on them to get the parameters
    spyOn(scope.fakeDialog, "dialog").andCallThrough();
    spyOn(scope.fakeDialog, "open").andCallThrough();

    // call edit
    scope.editClub(scope.clubs[0]);
    scope.$digest();
    httpBackend.flush();

    // check parameters passed in
    expect(scope.fakeDialog.dialog).toHaveBeenCalledWith({dialogFade: false, resolve: {club: jasmine.any(Function)}});
    expect(scope.fakeDialog.club.contact_officer).toEqual('Contact Officer 1');
    expect(scope.fakeDialog.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('club/club_edit.tpl.html', 'ClubEditCtrl');
  });
});
```

This seems to call the function and give the response into the club property on the fakeDialog object.

Comment: why do not use `$injector.invoke()` method how do it in real `$dialog` service?
Try `this.club = $injector.invoke(parameters.resolve.club);` instead of `this.club = parameters.resolve.club();`. And don't forget inject $injector service previously